# mongodb user logs storage best practice

Tags: mongodb, logging

I'm new to mongoDB and trying to figure out what would be the best way to store user logs. I identified two main solutions, but can't figure out which might be the best. If others come to mind, please feel free to share them ;)

1)The first is about storing a log in all the collections that I have. For instance, If I have the 'post', 'friends', 'sports' and 'music' collections, then I could create a log field in each document in each collection with all the logging info that I want to store.

2)The second way is to create an entire 'log' collection, each document having a type ('post', 'friends' ...) to identify the kind of log I'm storing along with the id of the document that is refered to.

What I really need is to be able to store and retrieve data (that is, everything but logs) as fast as possible. (so if I go with (1), I would have to always remove the logs from my selection queries since they would be useless most of the time)
Logs will only be accessed periodicaly (for reporting and stats mostly), yet will require to be mapped to their initial document (in case of (2)).
I will be creating logs for almost all the non log data to store (so storing logs inside each collection might be faster : one insert vs two).
Logging could also be done asynchronously to ease the load on the server.

With all that in mind, I can't really manage to find which is the best for my needs. Would anyone have any idea / comments to share ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you want to access your logs will play a big part in your design decision. By what criteria will you access your log documents? Will you have to query by type (e.g. post, friends) AND id (object id of the document)? Is there some other identifying feature? This can be extra overhead as you would have to read your 'type' collection first, get the id you're after, then query your logs collection. This creates a lot more read overhead.

What I would recommend is a separate logs collection as this keeps all related data in the one place. Then, for each log document, have a 1:1 mapping between document ids for your type collections, and your log collection. e.g. If you have a friend document, use the friend document's _id field as the _id field for your document in your logs collection. That way you can directly look up your log document without a second read. If you will have multiple log records for each type document, use an array in the log document and append each log record to it using mongo's $push. This would be a very efficient log architecture in terms of storage, write ($push requires no read - 'set and forget') and lookup time (smart 1:1 mapping - no more than one query needed if you have the _id).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about how my logs are going to be accessed yet. But the insights you provide here should help a lot !